# How to create a link in the Django website

Tags: django

I am working on the Django blog. I have created a url column in the admin post as follows.
[image]

however when I click the link in the page, the page jumps to the link which contains the localhost:8000 at the head of the url.
e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000/Yahoo/www.yahoo.com
[image]

I made a link as `<a href="{{ post.url }}">Visit yahoo.com!</a>` however this is probably a wrong way to do it.
Can you please advise me how to fix this issue?

my class in model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
content = models.TextField()
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
url = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, default='')
class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created_on']

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

my html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 left  top">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1>{% block title %} {{ object.title }} {% endblock title %}</h1>
        <p class=" text-muted">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on }}</p>
        <p class=" text-muted">{{ post.url }}</p>

        <a href="{{ post.url }}">Visit yahoo.com!</a>

        <p class="card-text ">{{ object.content | safe }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
  </div>
</div>
```

{% endblock content %}

Comment: You need to add the url scheme (the http:// or https://) bit at the beginning for the browser to be able to determine the URL isn't a relative one on the same site.

Comment: Cool! it worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://127.0.0.1:8000/Yahoo/www.yahoo.com

This implies that the link you indicated was made relative to your current path:

```
<a href="{{ post.url }}">Visit yahoo.com!</a>
```

Making it absolute by adding a prefix slash would not help either as that would still reference to your current running server

```
<a href="/{{ post.url }}">Visit yahoo.com!</a>
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/www.yahoo.com

If the post.url is external and outside your server, append a prefix of `http://` or `https://`

```
<a href="http://{{ post.url }}">Visit yahoo.com!</a>
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for your help